# oracle sql developer query error DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-109, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=WITH ISOLATION USE AND KEEP, DRIVER=3.69.56

Tags: db2, oracle-sqldeveloper, db2-luw

I am trying to run queries batches in oracle sql developer editor and get the following error message:

DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-109, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=WITH ISOLATION USE AND KEEP, DRIVER=3.69.56

it is hosted on windows and the oracle sql developer is version 17

I cannot use with ur as the queries are being run in oracle sql developer.

Please see examples of queries run, any ideas on how to get round the error

```
SELECT 'test' AS Data_Item, 'RC322' AS Test, 'dc' AS Source_Table, (SELECT COUNT() FROM schema.tableA ) AS VALUE FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
union all SELECT 'test' AS Data_Item, 'RC323' AS Test, 'dc' AS Source_Table, (SELECT COUNT() FROM schema.tableB ) AS VALUE FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
union all SELECT 'test' AS Data_Item, 'RC324' AS Test, 'dc' AS Source_Table, (SELECT COUNT() FROM schema.tableC ) AS VALUE FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
union all SELECT 'test' AS Data_Item, 'RC325' AS Test, 'dc' AS Source_Table, (SELECT COUNT() FROM schema.tableD ) AS VALUE FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
```

Comment: I don't see the same error (see [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=0de06467daedd5ea50ae9adfadf0fade)), maybe you are using DB2 for Z/OS. Does it change when you code `COUNT(*)` instead of `COUNT()` ?

Comment: i have tried both and same error message DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-109, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=WITH ISOLATION USE AND KEEP, DRIVER=3.69.56

Comment: Please edit your question to specify the platform of the Db2-SERVER ( z/os ,  i -series,  unix/ windows / linux / cloud ).  This is reported as text when you connect to the database.  Also specify the version of the Db2-server,  and the version of Oracle-SQL-Developer.

Comment: it is hosted on windows and the oracle sql developer is version 17

Comment: Tag added db2-luw. Please specify the __version__ of the Db2-server that is running on Windows. This information is returned as text when you connect, and it is also visible in the query output of `select * from sysibm.sysversions` .